# Error - The following splash screen or icon file does not exist: /res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

Tags: android, phonegap

While uploading the package on Build.Phonegap.com getting error for android

> Error - The following splash screen or icon file does not exist:
>   /res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)
cli-9.0.0 (5.0.1 / 8.0.0 / 7.0.0)

Thanks
Abhishek Mishra

I also tried to many alternatives but no success till now.

1. Changes the URL path as suggested in forum : but it not worked.
2. Deleted Apps from Build.PhoneGap.com portal and tried again.
3. Provided minimum and maximum SDK versions in Config URL
4. Changes CLI version in config.xml and again uploaded getting same problem

> Error - The following splash screen or icon file does not exist:
>   /res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

Comment: What does the error message suggest you? Maybe that you are missing an image file (`ic_launcher.png`) in a project folder (`/res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/`)?

Comment: File exist at the same path, I have cross verified it as well, You may also find discussion at "https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2641799"

Comment: Then possibly swap Phonegap for Android Studio. And get rid of the problem!

Comment: @AbhishekMishra did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem - and the file 100% exists at that location in the ZIP file I'm uploading

Comment: @ Andrew Newby: Yes it will work for 100%, I am doing the same. Please read the answer below, changes in the config file...renaming ic_launcher to the launcher and same changed in config.xml and rename the file...<icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/launcher.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-ldpi/launcher.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/launcher.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/launcher.png" density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/launcher.png" density="xxhdpi" />

Answer (score 5):

Please rename ic_launcher file with launcher ( remove ic_ ) could be problem with build.phonegap.com server, also update the config.xml with the same name..

```
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/launcher.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-ldpi/launcher.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/launcher.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/launcher.png" density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/launcher.png" density="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/launcher.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
```

create package and upload on build.phonegap.com

it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

its worked with renaming ic_launcher to launcher and same changed in config.xml

Comment: See below. What actually worked, I am guessing, is the path change from "www/res/.." to "res/.... Nothing to do with ic_launcher as against launcher (which makes no sense).

Answer (score 1):

OK. After many hours I have figured this out. The problem is NOT to do with things being named ic_launcher etc. It is to do with the source path as declared in the config.xml file.

The build is in two parts, as a look at the log file shows (when you have an error). In the first part of the build, the various resources are copied to various places in order to be available to the application itself. This part is common to both ios and android. In the second, and last, part of the build for ios, Build does clever things to provide the icons which apple wants. And here is the problem. Currently, this part of the build CANNOT find files with this path: "www/res/icon...". However, it can find the files if you remove the www: "res/icon...".

So the fix: in the config.xml file section dealing with IoS icons, just give the path as "res/icon/ios" or similar. Omit the root "www/" part of the path.

Slight update! Just discovered in doing an Android build that the same also applies to the Android icon paths, as given in Android platform icon path definitions in config.xml file. They too have to be changed to "res/icon/androld.." from "www/res/icon/android..".

Sounds like this is something which should be fixed in Build. In this context, "www/res" and "res" are, or should be, identical. Please fix.

Comment: I had this problem, and it actually WAS because the files were named 'ic_launcher'. I renamed them to 'launcher' and it worked fine. My path already excluded the www.

Answer (score 0):

Works with ic_ removed in your files and in xml, not in target. This is my code that builds successfully

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</edit-config>
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/drawable/launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/drawable/launcher_foreground.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/launcher.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/launcher_round.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-hdpi/launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-mdpi/launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-xhdpi/launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="www/res/icons/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been building apps with PhoneGap everyday with no such error until few minutes ago when I try to upload an updated source for an app I previously built successfully just a few weeks ago.

I tried all the recommendations I could find online with no success then I decoded to dig into the codava log. Only then did I notice that it was trying to copy the file from outside the "www" directory, even when the config file tells it exactly where to find the files.

**The Fix.**
I simply moved the resource folder to the root directory of my project and it solved the problem